# MySQL Workbench - Update Multiple Rows Base on Multiple Criterias

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the below table. I want to update the sales price for the product Ball in both row 1 and row 3 based on the Invoice_Date range and the product name.

I have the following sql syntax

```
update mydb_stock.sql_product_sales set sales_price = 7.5
where invoice_date between '20-03-2024' and '12-04-2024' and product_name = 'Ball';
```

The above syntax does not work properly. It only update the first row but subsequent rows are not updated.

| Invoice_Date | Product_Name | Sales_Price | Quantity | Total_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-03-2024 | Ball | 3.5 | 4 | 14 |
| 25-03-2024 | Racket | 2.0 | 3 | 6.0 |
| 12-04-2024 | Ball | 3.5 | 3 | 10.5 |

I would be grateful if you guys can be of help. Please note that the invoice_date is in varchar. I intentionally did that.

Thanks

Comment: i can not reproduce your problem https://dbfiddle.uk/-TL5c_gP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please note that the invoice_date is in varchar. I intentionally did that.

Please *don't* store your dates as text.  And if you must do that, you should at least store in YYYY-MM-DD iso format so that they sort properly.

That being said, we can workaround this problem by converting the invoice date to a bona fide date using the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```sql
UPDATE mydb_stock.sql_product_sales
SET sales_price = 7.5
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(invoice_date, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2024-03-20' AND '2024-12-04' AND
      product_name = 'Ball';
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. It worked. Can you explain to me why you have the date format in       '%d-%m-%Y' but the actual date starts with 'Y-m-d' as in 2024-03-20?

Comment: @KobbyAdom The return value coming from `STR_TO_DATE()` is an actual date, and therefore we need to compare it to valid date literals.  [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) for more information.